# Convert JSON response of LinkedHashmap List to Custom Java Response object

Tags: json, spring, api, rest, response

I came across a weird scenario.
I was calling a External API which is returning Lists of LinkedHashMap (E.g: List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>)

So the question is how to convert this JSON response to Custom Response object in Java

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to convert JSON response to Custom Response object in Java.

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                pathURL,
                HttpMethod.{GET/POST ..},
                createHeader(),
                Object.class
        );

        final List<LinkedHashMap> responseList = objectMapper
                .convertValue(
                        response.getBody(),
                        new TypeReference<List<LinkedHashMap>>() {
                        }
                );

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> responseMap = responseList.get(0);

        CustomResponseObj infoResp = objectMapper.convertValue(responseMap, CustomResponseObj.class);


private HttpEntity<?> createHeader() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    }
```